# Neo4j - LOAD-CSV not creating all nodes

Tags: neo4j, load-csv

I am just getting started on Neo4J, and I am trying to load some data into Neo4j 3.1 using LOAD CSV with the following script:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Fake59.csv" AS line
MERGE (person:Person {firstName: line.GivenName, middleInitial: line.MiddleInitial, lastName: line.Surname, title: line.Title,
gender: line.Gender, birthday: line.Birthday, bloodType: line.BloodType, weight: line.Pounds, height: line.FeetInches})
MERGE (contact:Contact {phoneNumber: line.TelephoneNumber, email: line.EmailAddress})
MERGE (person)-[:CONTACTED_AT]->(contact)
MERGE (color:Color {name: line.Color})
MERGE (person)-[:FAVORITE_COLOR]->(Color)
MERGE (address:Address {streetAddress: line.StreetAddress, city: line.City, zipCode: line.ZipCode})
MERGE (person)-[:LIVES_AT]->(address)
MERGE (state:State {abbr: line.State, name: line.StateFull})
MERGE (city)-[:STATE_OF]->(stage)
MERGE (country:Country {name: line.CountryFull, abbr: line.Country, code: line.TelephoneCountryCode})
MERGE (state)-[:IN_COUNTRY]->(country)
MERGE (credentials:Credentials {userName: line.Username, password: line.Password, GUID: line.GUID})
MERGE (person)-[:LOGS_in]->(credentials)
MERGE (browser:Browser {agent: line.BrowserUserAgent})
MERGE (person)-[:BROWSES_WITH]->(browser)
MERGE (creditCard:CreditCard {number: line.CCNumber, cvv2: line.CVV2, expireDate: line.CCExpires})
MERGE (person)-[:USES_CC]->(creditCard)
MERGE (creditCompany:CreditCompany {name: line.CCType})
MERGE (creditCard)-[:MANAGED_BY]->(creditCompany)
MERGE (occupation:Occupation {name: line.Occupation})
MERGE (person)-[:WORKS_AS]->(occupation)
MERGE (company:Company {name: line.Company})
MERGE (person)-[:WORKDS_FOR]->(company)
MERGE (company)-[:EMPLOYES]->(occupation)
MERGE (vehicle:Vehicle {name: line.Vehicle})
MERGE (person)-[:DRIVES]->(vehicle)
```

The input file has about 50k rows. It runs for a few hours the process does not finish, but after that time if I query the database I see that only the node type (Person) got created. If I run a smaller file with 3 entries only all the additional nodes and relationships are created.

I have already changed the amount of memory allocated to Neo4j and to the JVM, and still no success. I understand that MERGE takes longer than CREATE to be executed but I am trying to avoid duplication of nodes with the insert.

Any ideas or suggestions on what I should change or how I can improve this ?

Thank you,

--MD.

Comment: Do you have constraints and/or indexes on unique properties of the nodes in question? You'll need this in conjunction with Tomaz's suggestions to speed up your merges.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting your query into multiple smaller ones. Works better and is easier to manage. Also when using `MERGE` you should typically want to do it on a single property like an email for person or something unique and then use `ON CREATE SET`. Should fasten the query. Looks like this:

```
MERGE (contact:Contact {email: line.EmailAddress})
ON CREATE SET contact.phoneNumber = line.TelephoneNumber
```

In your case with the person where there is no single unique property you can use a combination of many, but know that every property you add in the `MERGE` slows down the query.

```
MERGE (person:Person {firstName: line.GivenName, middleInitial: line.MiddleInitial, lastName: line.Surname}) 
ON CREATE SET person.title = line.Title, person.gender = line.Gender,
person.birthday = line.Birthday, person.bloodType = line.BloodType, 
person.weight = line.Pounds, person.height = line.FeetInches
```

Comment: Thank you, for the suggestions Tomaz and InverseFalcon. One follow-up question. In the case of Person and Contact, I would be able to establish the edge/relationships with the node variables person and contact right ?